# Google map update markers with $.each iteration, setMap(Null) does not work

Tags: json, google-maps

Hi  I´ve been trying for a while now to update my markers from a JSON outout but with no luck. 
I cant remove my markers with gMarkers.setMap(null) even though I can see that data is stored within the Array. I assume i store data wrong?

My idea is to make use of an Interval

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Alarms in a Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gmap;
        var gMarkers = [];

        $(document).on('pageshow', '#map_index', function() {

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(58.990738, 16.210006);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

            loadData(); // init with active alarms
        });

        var loadData = function() { <!-- ---------------------------------- getActiveAlarms ------------------------------- -->

                setCenter(); <!-- set map to center -->

                //$('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');  //first clear all markers 


                $.getJSON('map/map_json.php', function(data) {
                    $.each(data.markers, function(j, marker) {

                        if (j == data.markers.length - 1) {
                            ANIMATION = google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE;
                        } else {
                            ANIMATION = google.maps.Animation.DROP;
                        }

                        if (marker.Status == '7') {
                            tmpIcon = Larm_active;
                        } else if (marker.Status == '5') {
                            tmpIcon = Larm_returned;
                        } else if (marker.Status == '3') {
                            tmpIcon = Larm_acknow;
                        } else if (marker.Status == '2') {
                            tmpIcon = Larm_blocked;
                        }

                        $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                            'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.Latitude, marker.Longitude),
                            'bounds': false,
                            'icon': tmpIcon,
                            'animation': ANIMATION
                        }).click(function() {
                            $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                                'content': '<div id="locTime">' + 'Tid:&nbsp;' + marker.AlarmTime + '</b>' + '</div>' + '<div id="LocArea">Area: ' + marker.Area + '</div>' + '<div id="locText">' + '<p>Larmtext: ' + marker.AlarmText + '</p>' + '</div>' + '<div id="locPos">Position av Objekt' + '<br />Longitude: ' + marker.Longitude + '<br />Latitude: ' + marker.Latitude + '</div>'



                            }, this);

                        });

                        gMarkers.push(data.markers);
                        console.log("load Markers");
                        console.log(gMarkers);
                    });
                });

            } <!-- getActiveAlarms -->

        var eraseMarkers = function() {
            console.log("enter removeMarkers");
            while (gMarkers[0]) {
                gMarkers.setMap(null);
            }

            gMarkers.length = 0;

        }


        var setCenter = function() {

            $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'center', new google.maps.LatLng(58.990738, 16.210006));
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 12);



        }
    </script>
    <link href="_css/customStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Javascript outside jquery Mobile -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <!-- Map Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_map/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var tmpIcon;
        var Larm_unreachable = new google.maps.MarkerImage('map/icons/Larm_unreachable.png');
        var Larm_active = new google.maps.MarkerImage('map/icons/Larm_active.png');
        var Larm_blocked = new google.maps.MarkerImage('map/icons/Larm_blocked.png');
        var Larm_acknow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('map/icons/Larm_acknow.png');
        var Larm_returned = new google.maps.MarkerImage('icons/Larm_returned.png');
        var User = new google.maps.MarkerImage('map/icons/User.png');
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="map_index">
        <div data-role="header"> <a href="menu.php" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline" rel="external">Home</a>
            <div class="ui-btn-right">
                <!-- <a href="#" id="user" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-user ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline">Where am I?</a>-->
                <a href="#" id="unreachable" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-alert ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline">Unreachable</a> <a href="#" id="locations" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-location ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline">Locations</a><a href="#" id="editLocations" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-edit ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline">editLocations</a> </div>
            <h1>Karta</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="content">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!-- Functions for buttons in navbar -->
            $("#unreachable").click(function() {
                getUnreachableAlarms();
            });
            $("#locations").click(function() {
                getActiveAlarms();
            });
            $("#editLocations").click(function() {
                eraseMarkers();
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ok, I´ve updated my script alot now I atleast can see that my array of markers is updating with correct amount of marker objects. however, no markers are visible.

```
map_Markers[i].setMap(null); //remove if not exist
```

If I remove this line they are visible but how can i update map if JSON output gives me one less on next iteration?
further help with an example in fiddle is much appr.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
      #map_canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- key=AIzaSyAlC-GSJ207WiUBtAG6zsNLNR5iChJtiSI -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Alarms in a Map</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp" async defer></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
var map_Markers = [];

function initMap()  {
    console.log("initMap");

    loadMarkers();
};

function CreateMarker(map, lat, lng, markerid) {
    console.log("CreateMarker"); 
        var objLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: objLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'my title',
            id: markerid
        });
        map_Markers.push(marker); // add in array
      return marker; 
}


function MarkerLocationUpdate(map, lat, lng, markerid ) {
    console.log("MarkerLocationUpdate");  
    var result = false;  
    for( i=0;i< map_Markers.length ; i++ ) {  
            if ( map_Markers[i].id == markerid ){  
                //update location on existing marker
                map_Markers[i].setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ) );
            result = true;
            }else{
                map_Markers[i].setMap(null); //remove if not exist

                }
        }
    return result;
}


var loadMarkers = function(){ <!-- ---------------------------------- loadMarkers ------------------------------- -->

    $.getJSON( 'map/map_json.php', function(data) { 
       $.each(data.markers, function(j, marker) {

               if (MarkerLocationUpdate(map,  marker.Latitude, marker.Longitude, marker.ID) == false ){
                 CreateMarker(map, marker.Latitude, marker.Longitude, marker.ID);
              }
     });//each loop
     console.log("Array is holding: "+map_Markers.length+" Object/s");
  }); //getJSON
}   



</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
          center: {lat: 58.990738, lng: 16.210006},
          zoom: 11
        });

 initMap();

 var t=setInterval(loadMarkers, 2000);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not your issue, but `google.maps.MarkerImage` was deprecated a long time ago (v3.10), replace it with a [`google.maps.Icon`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#convertingtoicon) anonymous object

Answer (score 0):

`gMarkers` is an array, not a marker.

possible fix:

```
var eraseMarkers = function(){
  console.log("enter removeMarkers");

  while(gMarkers.length){ 
   gMarkers.shift()//removes the first item from array
                   //and returns the item
     .setMap(null);
  }

}
```

Comment: gMarkers.shift(...).setMap is not a function Seems like I´m missing referens to the markers. My array gMarkers contains 5 objects with data for each marker. is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Typically I'd use an object literal to store markers which menas you can use `for var in ob` style for further operations but I think you should be able to use the `forEach` method to access each item in the array. At the end of the removal, to be sure, reset the array to empty.

```
var eraseMarkers = function(){
    gMarkers.forEach=function( e, i, a ){
        e.setMap( null );
    });
    gMarkers=[];
};
```